# Center vertical text in a multirow - \rotatebox[origin=c] don't work

Tags: longtable, rotating, multirow

I'm finally to finish the transcription of an article in my work, has a long table with a lot of text , for reasons of operating system (debian wheezy) had to be built in an supertabular environment (don't recognize tabularx + xtab). This is an extract of the table that continuous along multiple pages and basically has the same structure.

```
      \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
        \usepackage{rotating}
        \usepackage{supertabular} 
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{array}

        \begin{supertabular}{| c | p{4cm} | p{11cm} |}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Teoría}} & \textbf{Descripción} \\
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}[-3cm]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ENFOQUES DE COMPORTAMIENTO}}
         & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text. \\
        \cline{2-3}

        & Teoría sobre recompensas y castigos (líder positivo y líder negativo)(James Burns)  &  Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.\\
        \cline{2-3}

        & Liderazgo autocrático, participativo(Víctor Vroom y Phillip Yetton) y laissez-faire (Kurt Lewin) & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.  \\
        \cline{2-3} 

        & Teoría del Grid Gerencial (Robert Blake y Jane Mounton) & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.\\
        \hline

    \multirow{3}{*}[-3cm]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ENFOQUES DE CONTINGENCIA}}
         & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text. \\
        \cline{2-3}


        & Long Title & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.  \\
        \cline{2-3} 

        & Long Title & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.\\
        \hline

\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

My problem is when the cell brakes to continue to the next page the text doesn't and **overlaps the bottom of the page**. I already read all post related and couldn't solve the problem.

[image]

My problem is vertical rotate titles in multirow are not centered and when the cell brakes to continue to the next page the text doesn't and overlaps the bottom of the page. I already read all post related and couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). You are missing a package(multirow), `\begin{document}` `\end{document} and `\end{supertabular}. Please test your MWE before posting. This saves us the trouble of fixing stuff unnecessary. Also, you can format the code in the text with the code-button after selecting your code. This will give your question more attention, and better answers from more people. And please explain a bit better the problem with pages and such.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question, as your code was not compilable. Please check that the code is as you intended to post it.

Comment: Please, you have edited and posted this question a number of times, but every time it is still not compilable. Please check that before posting.  The code posted should be reflected by any screenshots posted, it clearly is not the same code, as you have a header with images and text in your screenshots.

Comment: yes, but i just post the problem in the table, the header belongs to the page format and not consider important to fill the code with elements that do not belong to the table, i will post the second question as a new question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

> ## Disclaimer
>
> The code below only attempts to fix the first problem. As the questions stands now, I fail to understand exactly what the second problem is.

#### The Problem with multirow

`multirow` often needs manual vertical adjustments, as described in its manual:

> #### Section 2, Using Multirow
>
> It’s just about impossible to deal correctly with descenders. The text will be set up centred, but it may then have a baseline that doesn’t match the baseline of the stuff beside it, in particular if the stuff beside it has descenders and text does not. This may result in a small misalignment. About all that can be done is to do a final touchup on text, using the fixup optional argument. (Hint: If you use a measure like .1ex, there’s a reasonable chance that the fixup will still be correct if you change the point size.)

So to this can be fixed by eyeballing it using `\multirow{4}{*}[-14ex]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ENFOQUES DE COMPORTAMIENTO}}` Of course, this is far from ideal, but I would suggest a very different approach to your whole table.

#### Suggestions

- Don't mix vertical and horizontal writing. Think about your reader. One would have to either rotate the page, or shift the neck. Use captions instead. Add a `\label{tab:example}` also, and this gives the bonus of being able to automaticly refering to the table, with page number and more, using `\ref{tab:example}` or `\pageref{tab:example}. Various packages enhances this also, like [cleverref](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref).
- Don't use vertical lines, except when the reading direction is vertical. The lines should follow the direction of the text. This gives a more natural flow and movement across the page for your reader.
- Use some varying widths of lines to make your some distintion between lines starting and ending a table, and lines which changes has the meaning of changing or separating the content within a table. Package `booktabs` has some very nicely defines lines, along with much else, including great advice. `\toprule`, `\mudrule` and `\bottomrule` are all lines which gives a great professional look.
- Depending on the content, serperating content within tables by lines can be a bit overkill. Adding som exstra space between those lines can give a much more natural and comfortable distinction. Again, from `booktabs` there is a command, `\addlinespace` which has a predefined(and ofcourse changeable] space which looks very nice.
- Save yourself some trouble. Set up your own macros for formatting and repeating stuff. For your headers, I have created a macro called `\tableHeader{text}` which sets the format. This makes the format of headers consistant through all of your tables, and if you decide later on that you wish to change the format, to say, small caps, you could just change that one macro, instead of every header of every table.

## Output, original with fixes vs. suggested improvements

[image]

#### Code, original with fixes

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{supertabular}{| c | p{4cm} | p{11cm} |} 

\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Teoría}} & \textbf{Descripción} \\
\hline 
\multirow{4}{*}[-14ex]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ENFOQUES DE COMPORTAMIENTO}} & Text Text Text Text & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text. \\ 
\cline{2-3}&&\\

& Teoría sobre recompensas y castigos (líder positivo y líder negativo)(James Burns) & Text Text Text Text  A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text.\\
\cline{2-3}&&\\

& Liderazgo autocrático, participativo(Víctor Vroom y Phillip Yetton) y laissez-faire (Kurt Lewin) & Text Text Text Text  A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text. \\ 
\cline{2-3}&&\\

& Teoría del Grid Gerencial (Robert Blake y Jane Mounton) & Text Text Text Text  A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text.\\ \hline
\end{supertabular}



\end{document}
```

#### Code, suggested improvements

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\tableHeader}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{ENFOQUES DE COMPORTAMIENTO}
\begin{tabular}{ p{4cm}  p{11cm} } 

\toprule
\tableHeader{Teoría} & \tableHeader{Descripción} \\
\midrule 
Text Text Text Text & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text. \\ 
\addlinespace

Teoría sobre recompensas y castigos (líder positivo y líder negativo)(James Burns) & Text Text Text Text  A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text.\\
\addlinespace

Liderazgo autocrático, participativo(Víctor Vroom y Phillip Yetton) y laissez-faire (Kurt Lewin) & Text Text Text Text  A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text. \\ 
\addlinespace

Teoría del Grid Gerencial (Robert Blake y Jane Mounton) & Text Text Text Text  A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer is really usefull. I can't I can not apply the improvement you've proposed beacause i'm just diagramming; besides the vertical title is a category in the table, the table is much longer with the same structure, followed by a multirow 3 and then a 6-cell more. There is still the problem when the table goes from one page to the next, you have any idea how to fix?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise you had another problem. Untill and if I find a solution, I think you should unaccept my answer. If you accept it this early, you will not get other answers from other people.

Comment: @Isadora I had an afterthought: If your first problem is solved, you might want to post a new question with your second question only. You could possibly link to this one. It is best to only post a single problem in a question.